# Macro that spellchecks worksheet and then locks it without erasing rules

Tags: excel, vba, spell-checking

I have a macro that unlocks my excel document, spellchecks, then locks the worksheet. However, upon locking the worksheet, it removes the rules regarding what a user can do in the locked spreadsheet (ex: add/delete rows, change box height/width, etc)

I've tried listing out the rules after `.Protect Password` but it doesn't work.

```
Sub ProtectSheetCheckSpellCheck()
'Update by Extendoffice 2018/11/2
Dim xRg As Range
On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveSheet
        .Unprotect ("Password123")
        Set xRg = .UsedRange
        xRg.CheckSpelling
        .Protect Password:="Password123", AllowInsertingRows:=True, AllowInsertingColumns:=True
    End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is being able to modify your worksheet without actually unprotecting it.
You can protect a sheet but allow VBA to make changes, whilst the user cannot:

`ActiveSheet.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.protect

Name: UserInterfaceOnly

Description: True to protect the user interface, but not macros. If this argument is omitted, protection applies both to macros and to the user interface.

This assumes the option was set to True when the sheet was protected in the first place.

---

Alternatively, you can store the status of the current protection settings in a `Protection` object:

`Dim myProtection as Protection
Set myProtection = ActiveSheet.Protection`

Which would look like this:
Note that for some reasons `.AllowEditRanges` return an error when read so I did not include it in the list.

```
Sub test()

    'Pick your Worksheet
    Dim mySheet As Worksheet
    Set mySheet = ActiveSheet

    'Unprotect it
    Dim myProtection As Protection
    Set myProtection = mySheet.Protection
    mySheet.Unprotect

    'Do your VBA things

    'Re Protect it
    With myProtection

        mySheet.Protect AllowFormattingCells:=.AllowFormattingCells, _
                        AllowFormattingColumns:=.AllowFormattingColumns, _
                        AllowFormattingRows:=.AllowFormattingRows, _
                        AllowInsertingColumns:=.AllowInsertingColumns, _
                        AllowInsertingRows:=.AllowInsertingRows, _
                        AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=.AllowInsertingHyperlinks, _
                        AllowDeletingColumns:=.AllowDeletingColumns, _
                        AllowDeletingRows:=.AllowDeletingRows, _
                        AllowSorting:=.AllowSorting, _
                        AllowFiltering:=.AllowFiltering, _
                        AllowUsingPivotTables:=.AllowUsingPivotTables

    End With

End Sub
```

Note: `.Protect` includes [DrawingObjects], [Scenarios], and [USerInterfaceOnly], whilst these settings are not provided by the `Protection` object. I understand the [Contents] parameter should relate to the `.AllowEditRanges`, but since it cannot be acessed I guess it will be skipped too,

Answer (score 0):

Sub Spellingscontrole()

'Made by Roger 12/02/2024

Dim xRg As Range

On Error Resume Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveSheet

```
   .Unprotect ("Password")
    Set xRg = .UsedRange
    xRg.CheckSpelling

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
ws.Protect Password:="Password", Scenarios:=False, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowInsertingRows:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=True
     
End With
```

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

'DrawingObjects:=True/False, Contents:=True/False, Scenarios:=True/False, _

```
'AllowFormattingCells:=True/False, AllowFormattingColumns:=True/False, _

'AllowFormattingRows:=True/False, AllowInsertingColumns:=True/False, _

'AllowInsertingRows:=True/False, AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=True/False, _

'AllowDeletingColumns:=True/False, AllowDeletingRows:=True/False, _

'AllowSorting:=True/False, AllowFiltering:=True/False
```